# How to change vertice labels on graph in bnlearn

Tags: r

I need help changing the vertex labels on graphs produced using `bnlearn`.

First, I run the program to get an undirected graph. When I plot the graph with `plot(data)` the vertices are labelled with `"V1,V2,V3..."`. Instead of this I want to plot them with their real labels.

Comment: Please _tag_ your question more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default plot should have the variable names as the node labels - you will need to share some code to show why this is not so. However, below is a method to manually change the node labels.

```
library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)

m <- hc(learning.test)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

#default plot
g <- graphviz.plot(m)

# change labels
z <- paste0("newlab_", letters[1:numNodes(g)])
names(z) <- nodes(g)
nAttrs <- list()
nAttrs$label <- z

# updated plots
plot(g, nodeAttrs=nAttrs)
```

For more info on `Rgraphviz` see [How To Plot A Graph Using Rgraphviz, Jeff Gentry](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bioconductor.org%2Fpackages%2Frelease%2Fbioc%2Fvignettes%2FRgraphviz%2Finst%2Fdoc%2FRgraphviz.pdf&ei=0qrDVJafHOOz7Aad5YHADw&usg=AFQjCNF1dr7DuAGT6bOzQjqhXGkHTtqHxA&bvm=bv.84349003,d.ZGU)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Unfortunately, this show both graphs. Is there any way to hide the first graph?

Comment: omit the `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`

Comment: Thank you for response, but this does not help me. I am writing an Rmarkdown document and use "knitr" to convert it to HTML. I am searching for a way that only the second graph appears in the HTML. I tried {r results="hide"} but the first graph shows anyway.

Comment: ah okay got you. Hmmm, thats annoying. I cant see how to suppress the plotting of the first figure, in interactive R or rmarkdown. One option for markdown is to have two chunks, with the first plot in one,  and use the option `include=FALSE` .

Comment: Another option , if all code in one chunk use `fig.keep='last'`